# JavaFX button reacting on second click not first

Tags: java, oop, button, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to create my very first application in JavaFX and I have a problem with Button that calls a method (for example to open another window) - I always have to click it twice in order to trigger action.

Here's my code from the Controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class ControllerSignIn {

    @FXML
    private Button forgot;
    @FXML
    private Button back;
    @FXML
    private Button signin;

    public void forgetPasswordClicked() {
        forgot.setOnAction(e -> ForgotPassword.setUpWindow()); //works on 2nd click
    }

    public void backClicked() {
        back.setOnAction(e -> ForgotPassword.closeWindow()); //works on 2nd click
    }

    public void signInClicked() {
        System.out.println("Sign In CLICKED"); //works on first click
    }
}
```

My methods are implemented here:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ForgotPassword {

    static Stage window;
    static Scene scene;
    static Parent root;

    private static void loadFXML() {
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(ForgotPassword.class.getResource("ForgotPassword.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setUpWindow() {
        loadFXML();

        scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("signin/SignIn.css");

        window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle("Forgot Password?");
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void closeWindow() {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you configured the call on those methods? E.g. did you define in your `FXML` that clicking `forgot` calls `forgetPasswordClicked()`?

Comment: Can you post your `ForgotPassword.fxml` or verify that it's configured properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have the following in your FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="forgot" onAction="#forgetPasswordClicked" />
```

This makes your button `forgot` call your method `forgetPasswordClicked()`. But instead of defining your logic to be executed when your button is clicked, the first time you say: "When this button is clicked, place an `action event` on my button which will call `setUpWindow()`"

```
forgot.setOnAction(e -> ForgotPassword.setUpWindow());
```

Therefore, your first click "sets up" the logic of your button. The second click, actually executes it. To solve this, either immediately use your logic as such:

```
public void forgetPasswordClicked() {
    ForgotPassword.setUpWindow();
}
```

or don't define the method to be called in your fxml, and move the initialization of your button (setting the action listener) to your initialization as following:

```
public class ControllerSignIn implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button forgot;
    @FXML
    private Button back;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        forgot.setOnAction(e -> ForgotPassword.setUpWindow());
        back.setOnAction(e -> ForgotPassword.closeWindow());
    }
}
```

This is also why your `signInClicked()` method works from the first click, because it actually executes the logic instead of setting up the handler first.

Comment: Thank you @Jaims for your help, the first option worked just fine! I also wanted to try the second but with no success, maybe I did some mistake so I wanted to ask which option is the better when I try to follow MVC.

Comment: @Kattia In both options, you're following MVC. Personally I prefer placing my method calls in the FXML (so the first option). It doesn't clutter my code as much. But most likely it's what you prefer personally. Also, when doing something more complicated than an action listener on a button, you'll have to initialize it beforehand. As long as you don't need it, just put it in FXML.